# Using autocomplete (Jquery) on AJAX loaded partial view (MVC4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-autocomplete

I've got a view to create Project models which contains (among other things) a table of company-related data.

I've added a button that does an AJAX call to retrieve a partial view and adds it to the table:

```
$("#addCompanyRoleProject").click(function () {
        cache: false,
        $.get('CompanyRoleProjectEntryRow', function (result) {

                $("#companyTable").append(result); // Add the row to the table

        }, "html").done(function (result) { 


            });

            return false;
        });
```

The partial view is a < tr > in wich one of the < td >'s has an input field:

```
<input class="company-role-project-company" type="text" data-containerPrefix="@ViewData["ContainerPrefix"]" />
```

I want that input field inside the partial view received by ajax to be an autocomplete (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) so that the user is able to select from a set of options on each < input > for each row of the table.

I can't seem to access the correspondent field on my AJAX call inside the main view. I've tried using "filter()" and "find()" on both the success and done functions.

I could put my javascript code inside the partial view, but it would then be replicated, not to mention possible ID colisions =\

Any ideias on how to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

I believe I have everything properly referenced in my view:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <<<< My JS code is here >>>>

}
```

And in my page's source code I can see:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

**EDIT 2:**

I followed Darin Dimitrov's advice and added this on the ajax success callback, after appending the result to the table:

```
$('input.company-role-project-company', result).autocomplete({
    ...define source etc...
});
```

But when I type something in the input field, it behaves like a regular text field...
Is there something wrong in my process of using an ajax call to: request a partial view, append it to the table, make it an autocomplete ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
    // Add entry to table
    $(function () {
        $("#addItemButton").click(function () {
            cache: false
            $.get('URL.......', function (template) {
                $('#table> tbody:last').append(template);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

   $(".the-class-used-in-the-desired-field-from-partial-view").live("click", function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "URL.........", type: "GET", dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { ....... };
                        }))
                    }
                })

            },
            minLength: 1,
            select: function (event, ui) {

                ... Do some magic ...
            }
        });
    });
```

I.E., I bound the autocomplete with a .live function, outside the AJAX.
Probably not the best way, but so far it's working as I want it to, for multiple entries.

Thanks to Darin Dimitrov anyway for pointing me to the right direction with the

```
$('input.company-role-project-company', result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this inside your AJAX success callback after you append the new partial markup to the DOM:

```
$('input.company-role-project-company', result).autocomplete({
    ...
});
```

Comment: That's a good ideia, but I get: "TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function" on firebug. Would you know the reason for this?

And yes, the Jquery libraries are correctly loaded, as I had success in making autocompletes in the main view (outside the partial views).

Comment: Did you reference the `jquery-ui` script?

Comment: Ok, I noticed that I had also included those libraries in my partial view (during my attempts of solving the problem) and now, after removing them, that error is gone.
The autocomplete doesn't work though. The input acts like a regular text input.